# using mmap in python

Tags: python, mmap

can somebody please explain how does 0 influence mmap in python in this case:

```
mmap.mmap(0 , 256, "some tag")
```

I thought that I always need to transfer file descriptor rather than 0, so why zero?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From reading CPython 2.7 source code, it seems that on Windows, specifying `fileno = 0` has the same effect as specifying `fileno = -1`, where the latter means "map anonymous memory".

Only `-1` is accepted on Unix: on my 64-bit Ubuntu box with Python 2.6.5, `mmap.mmap(0, 256)` fails with `errno=19 (No such device)` and `mmap.mmap(-1, 256)` works fine.

Bottom line: `fileno = 0` is a non-portable Windows-only variant of `fileno = -1`. It may get deprecated (there's even a commented-out warning in the code to that effect).

P.S. The CPython source file in question is `Modules/mmapmodule.c`.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [following discussion to know more](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t325298-shared-memory-modules.html).

In general if first parameter(fileno) is 0 or -1 then your statement says that you allocate 256 bytes of memory, shared across processes and ***not backed up by a file in the filesystem***.

By the way i have tested this code in WinXp with Python 2.5, 2.6, 2.7 and 3.0 and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

On *nix, file number 0 denotes standard input. So your call would map standard input if it came from a file (you can't mmap a terminal device) and if that file was opened read-write (otherwise you'd have to add `access=mmap.ACCESS_READ` or similar). In cases where this is indeed intended behavior, I'd suggest writing it as `sys.stdin.fileno()` instead.